# Selenium Python: Call a click event by a class name even class name is seperated by "space"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm facing a problem when trying to execute an automatic script of python using package "selenium"
Problem: If class name is separated by "space" then it throws an error.
Following is the instruction

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser.find_element_by_class_name("class name").click()
```

> Error: WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: Compound class
>   names not permitted\n  (Session info: chrome=37.0.2062.120)\n  (Driver
>   info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)'

for those classes which are not separated by "space" are executing fine.

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("class-name").click() // this is executing fine.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using css selectors

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".class.name").click()
```